# Striping the time out out a date and time vector

Tags: r

I wish to strip the time (hours and minuets) from the following vector but the time seems to defult to 00:00 when I use the following approach.

```
mytime = "2023-08-27 21:06:00Z"
format(strptime(mytime, "%F"), "%H:%M")
```

This returns 00:00 but here I want it to return 21:06, i've also tried wrapping as.POSIXct() around gtime but had the same results

Comment: `substr("2023-08-27 21:06:00Z", 12, 16)`? or `gsub(".* (\\d{2}:\\d{2}):.*", "\\1", "2023-08-27 21:06:00Z")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`%F` is Equivalent to `%Y-%m-%d`. So add `%H:%M:%S` or `%T` to get also the time.

```
format(strptime(mytime, "%F %H:%M:%S"), "%H:%M")
#[1] "21:06"

format(strptime(mytime, "%F %T"), "%H:%M")
#[1] "21:06"
```